# How can I profile the amount of memory a method call uses?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to check how much memory a method call consumes in .NET? I know there are methods in .NET but these get the total memory used by the application and not during the life of a method call (which is what I need).

I am aware that a profiler may help with this but I do not have access to a profiler (this is at work).

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean net-memory? That is, after-before, assuming it creates and returns something? Or, are you interested in how much it takes to do it's work?

Comment: If this is at work, just buy the profiler. If they can afford to pay a developer, they can afford to provide said developer with proper tools for the job.

Answer (score 0):

Afraid a profiler is really the only way to go, say [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) or [ANTS profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm), both of which have trial periods.

Is there any reason why you can't use a profiler at work?